# Removing multiple entries from ArrayList in Java by date

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have the arrayList called inPeople, which has this class stored in it named peopleIn. This is the data stored in the class

```
peopleIn( int scannerNum, Date date, int empNum){
```

So basically, my program is a system which reads through the logs of a punch clock to find out who's in the building. The problem is, if the person punches in a number of times, but never punches out, i end up with duplicates in my list. So basically, I need to keep the most recent punch in.

Can this be done?

Comment: You can use `Map` Then always previous value will get replace by new value for same key.

Comment: Or a tree map implementation if u need a sorted structure.

Comment: hmm, do you have some code you could share? @Ruchira

Comment: @melki0795 you can try and come up with your try. we are looking forward to help you

Comment: @melki0795 you can get some idea from my answer bellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map<Key,Value>`, If you put value for same `key`. previous value will be replace by current value.

Eg:

```
 Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
 map.put("emp1", "val1");
 map.put("emp2","val2");
 System.out.println(map);
 // now i am putting emp1, val3
 map.put("emp1","val3");
 System.out.println(map);
```

Out put:

```
 {emp2=val2, emp1=val1}
 {emp2=val2, emp1=val3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a Map, where the key is the employee number and the value is the date. This will prevent the duplicates.